# How to return the v-select value from a table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table (VDataTable), and for each row (person), there is a v-select (action), so i can't get the action that i chose for that person, because v-select is iterated, and i don't know how to do it.

```js
<VDataTable class="table" :headers="headers" :items="dataRef" :items-per-page="10" height="300"
          fixed-header>
          <template #item.fullName="{ item }">
            <div class="d-flex align-center">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column ms-3">
                <span class="d-block font-weight-medium text-high-emphasis text-truncate">{{ item.name }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
          <template #item.action="{ item }">
            <!-- <AppSelect :items="actionOptions" placeholder="Action" v-model="item.selectedAction" :key="item.id" /> -->
            <v-select clearable :items="actionOptions" v-model="item.selectedAction"></v-select>
          </template>
        </VDataTable>
```

here's an ai answer:

```js
watch(dataRef.value.participants, (newParticipants, oldParticipants) => {
        newParticipants.forEach((newParticipant, index) => {
            const oldParticipant = oldParticipants[index];
            if (newParticipant.selectedAction !== oldParticipant.selectedAction) {
                console.log(`Participant ${newParticipant.name} selected ${newParticipant.selectedAction}`);
            }
        });
    }, { deep: true });
```

Here's the data

```json
{
    "title": "FitPal",
    "description": "FitPal is a cutting-edge mobile application designed to revolutionize your fitness journey. Whether you're a seasoned fitness enthusiast or just starting, FitPal is your ultimate companion for achieving your health and wellness goals.",
    "point": 10,
    "starting_date": "2023-10-10",
    "ending_date": "2023-12-10",
    "remain": 10,
    "participants": [
        {"id": 0, "name": "John Doe", "email": "john.doe@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 1, "name": "Jane Smith", "email": "jane.smith@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 2, "name": "Bob Johnson", "email": "bob.johnson@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 3, "name": "Alice White", "email": "alice.white@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 4, "name": "Eve Black", "email": "eve.black@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 5, "name": "John Doe", "email": "john.doe@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 6, "name": "Jane Smith", "email": "jane.smith@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 7, "name": "Bob Johnson", "email": "bob.johnson@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 8, "name": "Alice White", "email": "alice.white@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" },
        {"id": 9, "name": "Eve Black", "email": "eve.black@example.com", "joinTime": "2023-11-13", "selectedAction": "waiting" }
    ]
}
```

and this is the actions

```js
const actionOptions = ["Waiting", "Testing", "Done"];
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Are you asking how to run a handler every time an action is selected?

Comment: when an action is changed in a row,  i want to know which row and what is the selected action. Either log it on the console or anything, just i want to get this info

Answer (score 0):

Set an [`@input`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#events-input) handler on the VSelect, which runs every time an action is selected. You can pass along the person as an argument:

```html
<template #item.action="{ item }">
  <v-select
    clearable
    :items="actionOptions"
    v-model="item.selectedAction"
    @input="action => onSelect(item, action)"
  ></v-select>
</template>
```